# Write a calculator for the identity sin² + cos² = 1

Tags: math, trigonometry

here's what I wrote:

```
public class Math {
  public static void main (String[] args){
    double degrees = Double.parseDouble(args[0]);
    double s = Math.sin(degrees);
    double c = Math.cos(degrees);
    double x = s*s + c*s;
    System.out.println(x);
  }
}
```

I want to enter a number as `args[0]` that goes into `sin()` and `cos()`. then I want to add the 2 variables making it equal 1, because `sin² + cos² = 1`. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: i made changes to my code to `s*s + c*c`, but i'm still getting the same error.

I'm also getting this error:

```
2 errors found:
File:...  [line: 4]
Error: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method sin(double)
  location: class Math
File:...  [line: 5]
Error: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method cos(double)
  location: class Math
```

Comment: Do you want to calculate `sin(x)^2 * cos(x)^2` (which is always `== 1`)? If so, where's the `^2`?

Comment: You shouldn't call your class `Math`. Call it something else instead.

Comment: I changed the word `Math` to Trig. it worked! Why though? I thought the class could be anything I want, so why can't I call it Math?

Comment: Yes you can, but the problem is: what do you mean with `Math.sin` if your class is called `Math`?

Comment: I'm pretty sure `Math.sin()` takes `radians` as input, not `degrees`...

Answer (score 3):

You are not squaring each term so you are calculating and printing `sin(x) + cos(x)`. Replace

```
double x = s + c;
```

with

```
double x = s*s + c*c;
```

and you should get the right behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a list of what I see going wrong:

- your class is called `Math`, but you're making a reference to the system's `Math` by using `Math.sin()` and `Math.cos()` -> rename your class to avoid the ambiguity
- you define `double x = s*s + c*s;`, which should of course be `double x = s*s + c*c;`
- you expect `Math.cos()` and `Math.sin()` to take their arguments in *degrees*, while they actually expect *radians*. It just happens to work because the identity holds for any input, but remember this for your next assignment :)